# Jquery DataTable - Cannot add rows on pages other than the first one

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm ajax-loading html table rows as a string, appending it to the table body and initializing a datatable:

```
// ajax_data.response_message is a string, containing rows like: "<tr><td>1</td><td>Some data</td></tr><td>2</td><td>Some data 2</td></tr>"
contracts_table.find('tbody').empty().append(ajax_data.response_message);
data_table = contracts_table.DataTable({

    fixedHeader: {
        header: true,
        footer: true
    },
    responsive: true,
    aoColumnDefs: [{
        'bSortable': false,
        'aTargets': ['_nosort']
    }],
    bAutoWidth: false,
    iDisplayLength: 20,
    aLengthMenu: [[5, 10, 20, 50, 100], [5, 10, 20, 50, 100]],
    }
});
```

And when I'm deleting or adding rows on the first page, it's working fine:

```
// rows is an array like: ["1288", "3218", ...]
var remove_rows = function(rows) {

    for (var key in rows) {
        if (rows.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log('remove: ');
            console.log(data_table.row($('.check-single#' + rows[key] +  '').closest('tr')).remove());
        }
    }
    data_table.draw(false);
};


// contract_rows is a string, containing rows like: "<tr><td>1</td><td>Some data</td></tr><td>2</td><td>Some data 2</td></tr>"
var add_rows = function(contract_rows) {

    var crows = contract_rows.split('</tr>');
    for (var key in crows) {
        if (crows.hasOwnProperty(key) && crows[key] != "") {
            //
            var new_row = crows[key] + '</tr>';
            console.log('add: ');
            console.log(data_table.row.add($(new_row)[0]));
        }
    }
    data_table.draw(false);
};
```

On other pages it's deleting rows successfully, BUT is not adding new rows. I couldn't find the reason why. Could someone help me with this, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this approach is suffering from race conditions and the fact that you're not leveraging DataTables and are effectively mixing apples and oranges. This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/xsfL65sr/1/) illustrates what you're trying to do at the minute:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mockData = "<tr><td>Sonya Frost</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>23</td><td>2008/12/13</td><td>$103,600</td></tr><tr><td>Jena Gaines</td><td>Office Manager</td><td>London</td><td>30</td><td>2008/12/19</td><td>$90,560</td></tr>"
    peopleTable = $('#example');
    setTimeout(function(){
        peopleTable.find("tbody").empty().append(mockData)
    }, 500);
    var dt = peopleTable.DataTable();
});
```

If you change your ajax result to return just the data as an array or arrays like this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/xsfL65sr/3/) and use the DataTable API to `clear` and then `add` the new data then you should find things much easier.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mockData = [
        [
            "Sonya Frost",
            "Software Engineer",
            "Edinburgh",
            "23",
            "2008/12/13",
            "$103,600"
        ],
        [
            "Jena Gaines",
            "Office Manager",
            "London",
            "30",
            "2008/12/19",
            "$90,560"
        ]
    ],
    peopleTable = $('#example');
    setTimeout(function(){
        dt.clear().rows.add(mockData).draw();
    }, 500);
    var dt = peopleTable.DataTable();
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think clearing the table every time I add rows will cause performance issues, lots of manipulations are made frequently upon the table and the table holds a large set of data (about 1000 rows). That is why I was initializing it with plain string data and manipulating selected rows separately. Anyway, thank you for answering.

Comment: If that's the case just remove the `clear()`. I didn't realise that that was your use case.